# MKMapview only with Annotations (no streets, buildings, ..) just a white background

Tags: ios, dictionary, mapkit

Is it possible to view on a map only the annotations?
So that there are no streets, buildings, ... shown, just a white backgound with annotations?

Comment: No answer? Please tell me if it's possible or not, thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the easiest way to do this would probably be to create an `MKTileOverlay`, then for each tile request, return a square, white, `256px` image. Also, set `canReplaceMapContent` to `YES` so that Apple's maps aren't downloaded or drawn.